# Metatag type issue in linkedin

Tags: linkedin-api

We are passing og:type as image but when i checked linkedin debugger it is taking type = video, as we need image here but linkedin assumes it has video and play button is appearing above image.

Please refer the images [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yi8r4.png [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TTpmO.png

In pic1 we are passing og:type as image, but in the pic2 in linkedin debugger it is taking type as video, we want the linkedin debugger also to take image instead of video.

URL: https://breakingdepression.eu